# Soap call using HttpsUrlConnection gives a 500 using java

Tags: java, soap, https, soap-client, httpsurlconnection

I have been trying for over a month already reading everything available to me on stackoverflow and I still couldn't get to solve this issue, I need to call a soap webservice and get a response which would contain a url. I get an error 500/400 based on my diffrerent tests. Any help would be deeply appreciated (1):

The client code is as follows:

```
URL oURL = null;
    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    
    try {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        oURL = new URL(soapEndpointUrl);
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) oURL.openConnection();
        
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setUseCaches (false);
        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        
        SOAPMessage message = createSOAPRequest(oppBean, context, soapEndpointUrl, soapAction);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(bout);
        String strMsg = new String(bout.toByteArray());
        
        OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
        out.write(reproducerUrlEncodedString((strMsg)).getBytes());
        out.close();
        
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        
        Reader streamReader = null;
        
        if (responseCode > 299) {
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream());
        } else {
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
        }
        
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                streamReader)) {

            String line;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
           
           if(responseCode == 200) {
              logger.debug(response.toString());
           }
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

I always get a 500 if I use the request as it is. And an error 400 if I encode the double quotes. The team that made the service is not able to fetch the logs for the error 500. They built it using C#.

The request xml that they expect me to send is as below:

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:hen="example.com"
xmlns:hen1="http://schemas.xyz.org/2004/07/xyz.WcfServices.xyz.IO.Initialize"
xmlns:hen2="example.com">
<soap:Header
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <To>https://service.xyz.fr/Company/ABC/ABC.svc</To>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <hen:XyzMethod>
        <hen:entree>
            <hen1:AdresseLigne1Souscripteur>35</hen1:AdresseLigne1Souscripteur>
            <hen1:AdresseLigne2Souscripteur>avenue de la Republique</hen1:AdresseLigne2Souscripteur>
            <hen1:AdresseLigne3Souscripteur>Paris 13th</hen1:AdresseLigne3Souscripteur>
            <hen1:AdresseMailEquipeCommercialConnecte>bch@xyz.com</hen1:AdresseMailEquipeCommercialConnecte>
            <hen1:AdresseServiceCommercialLigne1>AdresseServiceCommercialLigne1</hen1:AdresseServiceCommercialLigne1>
            <hen1:AdresseServiceCommercialLigne3>AdresseServiceCommercialLigne3</hen1:AdresseServiceCommercialLigne3>
            <hen1:CanalVente>7</hen1:CanalVente>
            <hen1:CodexyzCiviliteSouscripteur>01</hen1:CodexyzCiviliteSouscripteur>
            <hen1:CodexyzRegime>0001</hen1:CodexyzRegime>
            <hen1:CodexyzSexeSouscripteur>FE</hen1:CodexyzSexeSouscripteur>
            <hen1:CodexyzTypeSouscripteur>EXCLIENT</hen1:CodexyzTypeSouscripteur>
            <hen1:CodeIsoPaysSouscripteur>FR</hen1:CodeIsoPaysSouscripteur>
            <hen1:CodeMotifOpportunite>NRENS</hen1:CodeMotifOpportunite>
            <hen1:CodePostalServiceCommercial>59650</hen1:CodePostalServiceCommercial>
            <hen1:CodePostalSouscripteur>59650</hen1:CodePostalSouscripteur>
            <hen1:CodeProduitxyz>66</hen1:CodeProduitxyz>
            <hen1:CodeServiceCommercial>20</hen1:CodeServiceCommercial>
            <hen1:DateEffetContrat>01/01/2021</hen1:DateEffetContrat>
            <hen1:DateNaissanceSouscripteur>07/07/1972</hen1:DateNaissanceSouscripteur>
            <hen1:EmailSouscripteur>alexeyevitch@test.com</hen1:EmailSouscripteur>
            <hen1:LibelleServiceCommercial>xyz - DÃ©partement Individuels</hen1:LibelleServiceCommercial>
            <hen1:NomBeneficiaire>VILLANI</hen1:NomBeneficiaire>
            <hen1:NomCommercial>Test BCH</hen1:NomCommercial>
            <hen1:NumeroOpportunite>2020/06/0009</hen1:NumeroOpportunite>
            <hen1:NumeroOpportuniteCrm>1122159</hen1:NumeroOpportuniteCrm>
            <hen1:OpportuniteADupliquer>1122158</hen1:OpportuniteADupliquer>
            <hen1:PrenomBeneficiaire>MILAN</hen1:PrenomBeneficiaire>
            <hen1:PrenomCommercial>BCH Test</hen1:PrenomCommercial>
            <hen1:TelephoneFixeSouscripteur/>
            <hen1:TelephonePortableSouscripteur>+33 6 63 44 21 84</hen1:TelephonePortableSouscripteur>
            <hen1:TelephoneServiceCommercial>03 28 76 37 00</hen1:TelephoneServiceCommercial>
            <hen1:VilleServiceCommercial>VILLENEUVE Dâ€™ASCQ</hen1:VilleServiceCommercial>
            <hen1:VilleSouscripteur>VILLENEUVE D'ASCQ</hen1:VilleSouscripteur>
        </hen:entree>
    </hen:XyzMethod>
</soap:Body>
```

</soap:Envelope>

I thought of generating the client using the wsimport technique, but I got some errors that the methods didn't respect the SOAP 1.2 binding so I could not go ahead with this technique.

Good news is that the request xml works well with soapui and I get a favourable response. But the same request fails via java.

Some info on the MessageFactory etc:

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
```

Static. Calling all autobots. I'm Optimus prime, and I send this message to all autobots taking refuge among the stars. We are here. We are waiting - Optimus Prime Static

Any help would be deeply appreciated (2) . Please let me know if you need any additional info, incase if I missed to add something.

Some references:
[Soap calls using Java](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/06/29/how-to-call-a-call-a-webservice-directly-from-java-without-webservice-library/)

Comment: Did you try to print the serialized message sent by your app to the WS? If it works with SoapUI using the request.xml, then the best way to find the problem is to compare the request.xml to what you send via your app.

Comment: both are exactly the same, the request generated by java is what I use for testing in soap-ui @Imaguest

Comment: What is the exception on server side?

Comment: this is necessarily a difference between the two requests sent. Since you can't get the logs from server, in your case, i'll try to sniff the communications(using Wireshark or your favorite network sniffer) and compare them (SoapUI vs Java app). You'll be able to see that the two transactions aren't the same and maybe find the reason why (could be headers, encoding, whatever)